# How can we use MEF in MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, mef

I am a Silverlight developer and have used MEF in MMVM pattern in Silverlight. How can we use MEF in Asp.Net MVC application? How do I begin? There is no CompositionIniliazer.SatisfyImports. How do I begin with MEF?

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look to [Implementing MEF with ASP.NET MVC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/760563/implementing-mef-with-asp-net-mvc) SO post.
Also [MEF and ASP.NET MVC sample](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/hammett/archive/2009/04/23/mef-and-asp-net-mvc-sample.aspx) from http://blogs.msdn.com will be helpful for you.
You will find more posts [here](http://www.google.com/?search=using%20mef%20in%20mvc3).